# Fixed effect model based on a given formula using lme4 from R

Tags: r, model, lme4

Given a formula as follows:

```
y = β0 + β1·(x1 - 30) + β2·(x2 - 3) + β3·(x3 - 10)+ β4·x4 + β5·x6 + β6·x6·(x2-3) + e
```

How can I construct a model in R using package such as `lme4`, etc? Thanks at advance.

My trial so far, but it's obviously not a model as formula required.

```
library(lme4)
# model <- lmer((y ~ (x1 -30) + (x2 - 3) + (x3-10) + x4 + x5 + (x6 | (x2-3))), data = df, REML = FALSE) this line not work
model <- lmer(y ~ x1 + (1|x2),  data = df, REML = FALSE)
model
```

Out:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood [lmerMod
]
Formula: y ~ x1 + (1 | x2)
   Data: df
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 22427.02  22452.94 -11209.51  22419.02      4821 
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 cal      (Intercept) 0.3649  
 Residual             2.4430  
Number of obs: 4825, groups:  cal, 4785
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)          x1  
   19.68828      0.05818
```

Comment: I don't see a random effect in your formula.. so do you need a linear mixed model? The short answer is that you can manipulate the variables in the data frame first before fitting

Comment: otherwise everything goes into the intercept

Comment: Maybe you need to know the meaning of variables?

Comment: I means wether it's necessary to know the meaning of `y, x1, x2...`, for example, `y` is salary, `x1` is `age`, `x2` is `education`, etc, to build a model using `lme4`?

Comment: Btw, could you help to answer the question?